# Defining EventEmitter handler in another module not exporting the functionality

Tags: node.js, events, es6-modules, eventemitter

I have an `EventEmitter` instance declared and exported in one module (lets say `index.ts`) like this

```
class Logger extends EventEmitter {};

/* Logger instance */
export const logger: Logger = new Logger();
```

in another module i imported this `logger` instance and defined a few handlers. (`handlers.ts`)

```
logger.on(LOG_TRIGGER, (data: ILogTrigger): void => {
  const symbol: string = data.symbol;
  const change: number = data.change;
  const price: number = data.last_price;
  logger.logTrigger(symbol, price, change);
});
```

But when i import the logger instance in a foreign module from the `index.ts` file and emit the events. It doesn't get triggered. But, it gets triggered when both the handlers and the declaration are in one file. What's going on here?

**Exporting the class into the handler module is a solution, But my question is that: Can we export the instance of a class and define more handlers on it in a separate module?**

Comment: Sounds like you emitted events without ever loading the `handlers.ts` module into your application?

Comment: I exported the instance of the Logger from the ‘index.ts’ and imported it into the handler.ts where I defined the event handlers. Is there any way to do this and still be able to emit from other modules. 

Note that the class is instanciated and then exported before event handlers are defined in another module.

Comment: Yes, this works. But you need to actually load and execute `handlers.ts` (e.g. `import` it in your entrypoint module) to install the handlers, as nothing else depends on it. Are you doing that? If yes, please post that code as well, if no, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the module in which I'm defining my event handler's is not being reached by the process at all. Importing the external module where i defined my handlers into the module where the event emitter instance is being initialized [OR] Importing to the main process where the code is initiated helped solved this issue.

```
import "./external-handler-module.ts"
```

This makes the code "reachable" by the application process.